# Masking pixels or doing convolutional LSTM classification with Keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, masking

I have a sequence of multi-band images, say each sample is a tensor of size (50, 6, 30, 30) where 50 is the number of image frames in sequence, 6 is number of bands per pixel, and 30x30 is the spatial dimension of the image. The ground truth map is  of size 30x30, but it is one-hot encoded (to use crossentropy loss) o 7 classes, so it is a tensor of size (1, 7, 30, 30).I want to use a combination of convolutional and LSTM (or use an integrated ConvLSTM2D layer) for my classification task, but there are below problems:

1- Not every point has a valid label at the output map (i.e. some one-hot vectors are all-zero),

2- Not every pixel has a valid value in every time stamp. So, at every given time stamp, some of the pixels may have zero value (means invalid) for all of their band values.

I read many Q&As on how to handle this issue and I think I should use sample_weights option to mask the invalid points and classes but I am really uncertain how to do it. Sample_weights should be applied to every pixel and each timestamp independently. I think I can manage it if I didn't have the convolution part (a 2D approach). But don't understand how it works when convolution is in place, because some pixel values in convolution window are valid and some are invalid.If I mask those invalid pixels at a specific time (that still I don't know how to do it), what will happen to the chain of forward and backward propagation and loss calculation? I think it will be ruined!
Looking for comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Problem 1- For pixels where do not have class at all you can introduce a new class with a label for example noise,
        it means not in your one hot encode you have value for that as well and weights will be generated accordingly for those pixels for noise class
        this is an indirect way to achieve the same thing you do with sample weight 
         cause in the sample_weight technique you tell keras or sklearn that what is the weightage of the parameter or sample ratio of the weights.

Problem 2- To answer part 2 consider the possible use cases for example for these invalid values class value can be there in hot encode vector or it will be all zeros?
            or you can preprocess and add these to the noise class as well then point 2 will be handled by point 1 automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My basic problem is how to mix the weighting with convolution. If it was 2D temporal-spectral data, masking by weighting either classes or samples would not be a problem. But with convolution everything is mixed, and note that the invalid data/labels can happen everywhere in the map and time stamp (any pixel can have some invalid data (at all bands) at one time stamp but has valid data at another time stamp.So it is not the case that the mentioned pixel is noise.) Actually it is a Landsat data, and the pixel is cloudy at some times so that reading should be masked.